# Getting error in displayig data from sqlite in the HTML template

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I am trying to display the images from databse to HTML template,but I am getting an import error:

```
return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: Image
```

here are the files:models.py

from django.db import models

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.

    class Image(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        image = models.FileField(upload_to='post_image', blank=True)
```

#### views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.db import connection
from accounts.models import Image
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('''SELECT image FROM Image where 'user'="admin"''')
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    print (row)
    args = {'row':row}
    return render(request, 'accounts/home.html', args)
```

#### home.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
<h1>Home</h1>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>HOME</title>
        {% block head %}
        <title>HOME</title>
        {% endblock %}
    </head>
        <body>
        <h2 align="center"> SQL Queries display </align> </h2>

    {% block content %}

    {{ row }}

    {% endblock %}

            {% block body %}
            <h1>Base</h1>
            {% endblock %}
        </body>
</html>
```

I am storing data on the file system, I have uploaded two images for the user 'admin'.

Comment: Have you migrated your models?

Comment: yes I have migrated my code..

Comment: The name of the model and the name of the table on the db are not the same! Add an s to cursor.execute('''... From Images ...

Comment: Or better make use of the model to select that images.

Comment: The table name most likely includes the app name `accounts`. Try `accounts_image` as table name.

Comment: Can you explain why you are using raw SQL in the first place? The whole point of defining a model is that you then use it in your views and templates.

Comment: @Eineki ("'...From Images didn't work

Comment: @DanielRoseman But this should work also...

Answer (score 1):

As your App is named "accounts", Django is probably creating the table as "accounts_image", and the resulting query should be:

```
"SELECT image FROM accounts_image WHERE ..."
```

Why don't you use the ORM to get the data?  It'll be easier for you:

```
row = Image.objects.get(user__username="admin")
```

Also, remember that the "user" field in the Image model is a ForeignKey, which means that you can't query user="admin".